# Ubuntu 12.04 MTP support for Android 4.4

Tags: 12.04, android, mtp

I have been using gvfs-mtp to get access to the my Nexus 4 (Android 4.3) memory through MTP.

Since my Nexus 4 get android 4.4 updates, I can no longer transfer files to it.

I have tried several methods, including

1. Go-mtpfs
2. gvfs-mtp
3. gMtp (keep on crashing)

and none of the above works.

Any idea to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report?

Answer (score 2):

Not really the ideal solution but you can try [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) for transfer files or if you are able to, go back to the previos jellybean version.

This might be a better question for the android stack exchange since it doesn't really have much to do with Ubuntu support, luck.